# How to capture response from PayPal payment using PHP script?

Tags: php, paypal, response, payment, checkout

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="Y43MR9C35KS88">
        <input class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Recharge via PayPal or Credit Card">
</form>
```

The above code was generated from a PayPal business account. This takes a buyer to PayPal website where he can go through the payment process. The payment amount was fixed to $20 during generating the code. I need to capture the payment amount and confirmation of payment so that I can update a local database table to record the payment.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To receive information about done/pending/canceled payments you should use PayPal's Instant Payment Notification (IPN). You can add a `notify_url` to the form with the URL where the information should go to after the payment process.

More information about IPN (including fields):
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

More information about possible form fields
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

To save/capture the values you need to read out the relevant $_REQUEST or $_GET variable like
`$amount = $_REQUEST["mc_gross"];` or `$amount = $_GET["mc_gross"];`

Hope it helps,
Sascha

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GET method with the response from paypal.

```
$amount = $_GET['amt']; 
$currency = $_GET['cc'];
$check_amount = '20.00';
$check_currency='USD';

if($amount==$check_amount && $currency==$check_currency)
{
// Do stuff for correct value
}
else
{
// Do stuff if failed
}
```